# K8s no internet connection inside the container

Tags: kubernetes, alpine-linux, flannel, coredns

I installed a clean K8s cluster in virtual machines (Debian 10). After the installation and the integration into my landscape, I checked the connectivity inside my testing alpine image. As result the connection of outgoing traffic not working and no information was inside the coreDNS log. I used the workaround on my build image to overwrite my /etc/resolv.conf and replace the DNS entries (e.g. set 1.1.1.1 as Nameserver). After that temporary "hack" the connection to the internet works perfectly. But the workaround is not a long term solution and I want to use the official way. Inside the documentation of K8s coreDNS, I found the forward section and I interpret the flag like an option, to forward the inquiry to the predefined local resolver. I think the forwarding to the local resolv.conf and the resolve process works not correctly. Can anyone help me to solve that issue?

**Basic setup:**

- K8s version: 1.19.0
- K8s setup: 1 master + 2 worker nodes
- Based on: Debian 10 VM's
- CNI: Flannel

**Status of CoreDNS Pods**

```
kube-system            coredns-xxxx 1/1     Running   1          26h
kube-system            coredns-yyyy 1/1     Running   1          26h
```

**CoreDNS Log:**

```
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 4e235fcc3696966e76816bcd9034ebc7
CoreDNS-1.6.7
```

**CoreDNS config:**

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: ""
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "219"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: xxx
```

**Ouput alpine image:**

```
/ # nslookup -debug google.de
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

**Output of pods resolv.conf**

```
/ # cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.96.0.10
search development.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local invalid
options ndots:5
```

**Output of host resolv.conf**

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 213.136.95.11
nameserver 213.136.95.10
search invalid
```

**Output of host /run/flannel/subnet.env**

```
cat /run/flannel/subnet.env
FLANNEL_NETWORK=10.244.0.0/16
FLANNEL_SUBNET=10.244.0.1/24
FLANNEL_MTU=1450
FLANNEL_IPMASQ=true
```

**Output of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide`**

```
coredns-54694b8f47-4sm4t                 1/1     Running   0          14d   10.244.1.48    xxx3-node-1   <none>           <none>
coredns-54694b8f47-6c7zh                 1/1     Running   0          14d   10.244.0.43    xxx2-master   <none>           <none>
coredns-54694b8f47-lcthf                 1/1     Running   0          14d   10.244.2.88    xxx4-node-2   <none>           <none>
etcd-xxx2-master                      1/1     Running   7          27d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx2-master   <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-xxx2-master            1/1     Running   7          27d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx2-master   <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-xxx2-master   1/1     Running   7          27d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx2-master   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-4w8zl              1/1     Running   8          28d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx2-master   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-w7m44              1/1     Running   7          28d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx3-node-1   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-xztqm              1/1     Running   6          28d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx4-node-2   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-dfs85                         1/1     Running   4          28d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx4-node-2   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-m4hl2                         1/1     Running   4          28d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx3-node-1   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-s7p4s                         1/1     Running   8          28d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx2-master   <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-xxx2-master            1/1     Running   7          27d   xxx.xx.xx.xxx   xxx2-master   <none>           <none>
```

Comment: what is the content of resolve.conf inside pod? Also whats the status of coredns pods?

Comment: Hi @AbhiGadroo, I add the status and content of the resolv.conf to the main post.

Comment: As far as I have used this, till now I didnt had to do any hacks with default configuration. Everything seems good here. Can you  hardcode 8.8.8.8 in your etc resolve on hostmachines?  And do a machine reboot?

Comment: @AbhiGadroo Sure, but don't understand the difference between the actual configuration of my host resolv.conf. I use the DNS servers of my provider and you Google DNS server. I add the host resolv.conf to the main post.

Comment: Does anyone have another idea?

Comment: Yesterday I set the host, nameserver entries manually to 1.1.1.1. -> No result change. The pod can't resolve the example google.com url. I can validate that the problem is definitely the internal DNS server. It's possible to ping 8.8.8.8. I invested time to analyse the journalctl and identified no errors inside the log. Does anyone have a idea to check the connection between the DNS server and pod?

Comment: @ZPascal Does [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) helps?

Comment: @OhHiMark I already tested it before creating the thread. Unfortunately it didn't help and the resolution still doesn't work. I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: @ZPascal You probably checked it already but is there any chance that a firewall is blocking the connection?

Comment: I fixed the dns problems by scaling up the coredns pods. I post later a detailed tutorial to fix the problem. Now I am faced with another problem, my DNS resolution does not work in all images within the cluster. I will open a separate thread for this issue.

Comment: @OhHiMark It's definitely a valid option. I use iptables to filter by the specific incoming ip and control the traffic. I think the problem was that the two coreDNS Pods were on the same node.The scale up made it possible to deploy the coreDNS pods on each node. After this step I could partially resolve the corresponding addresses.

Comment: This would be better without the word 'slave'. K3S uses the terms 'server' and 'agent', 
 or maybe you could use control-plane and worker-plane. There is no need to be using outdated pejorative terms.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer You are absolutely right! I have adapted this immediately.

Answer (score 4):

**Problem:**

The (two) coreDNS pods were only deployed on the master node. You can check the settings with this command.

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide | grep coredns
```

**Solution:**

I could solve the problem by scaling up the coreDNS pods and edit the deployment configuration. The following commands must be executed.

1. `kubectl edit deployment coredns -n kube-system`
2. `Set replicas value to node quantity e.g. 3`
3. `kubectl patch deployment coredns -n kube-system -p "{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"annotations\":{\"force-update/updated-at\":\"$(date +%s)\"}}}}}"`
4. `kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide | grep coredns`

**Source**

- https://blog.dbi-services.com/kubernetes-dns-resolution-using-coredns-force-update-deployment/

**Hint**

If you still have a problem with your coreDNS and your DNS resolution works sporadically, take a look at this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1033711/k8s-no-dns-resolution-on-all-used-test-images).

Comment: does it mean that you have 3 coredns pods on 3 nodes or 3 pods on master node only?  What's  the output of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide` ?

Comment: @Nick I have three coreDNS pods on 3 different nodes. On each node there is one pod. I add the output to the main post.

Comment: Thanks. I'd set up a minikube deployement and do not know why it happend but it fixed for me.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'm glad that my solution was helpful to you.

Comment: I'm using cluster-autoscaler and don't know how to scale up | down dynamically coreDns pod replica during the period while new instance arrived and terminated....Is there any other solution, if above is the case?